# How to avoid retrieving objects that are already retrieved in Parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, message, messaging, pfobject

I'm making an app that are retrieving messages as PFObjects with Parse, and I retrieve these messages in my viewDidLoad-function. The problem is that this function retrieves the messages every time the page is loaded.

So I thought about making a list in my core data where I save all the id's of my already retrieved objects, and then compare the id of the newest(and possibly already retrieved) object that is being retrieved to the ones in this list.

Because I don't wanna use core data unnecessary, I was just wondering if anyone had a other and more efficient solution to this problem.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check out anypic from Parse... Its a very well documented iOS application that does everything a basic application would need to do to handle caching objects in memory and limiting API requests sent to the parse server

Comment: Instead of comparing the object ids in local, why don't you send the existing object ids as list and use the predicate not contained? Then all retrieved objects are new ones and you can save them in core data.